# put same ID different rows in one line

Tags: sql-server, pivot

How could I put those multiple rows into one line, and the contents are in different columns:

From:

```
ID          |   Subject1/Catalog/Session
10868952    |   NUR/3110/D507
10868952    |   NUR/3110/D512
10868952    |   NUR/4010/D523
10868952    |   NUR/4010/HD20
```

To

```
ID       |Subject1/Catalog/Session |Subject2/Catalog/Session | Subject3/Catalog/Session   |Subject4/Catalog/Session | Subject5/Catalog/Session

10868952 |NUR/3110/D507            | NUR/3110/D512           | NUR/4010/D523              | NUR/4010/HD20           |
```

Comment: This is called "pivot". Search for it, it gets asked about once a week.

Comment: Does ordering by ID and then by Subject1/Catalog/Session ie SELECT ID,Subject1/Catalog/Session FROM [sometable] ORDER BY ID,Subject1/Catalog/Session give the Subject1/Catalog/Session column in order of subject 1,2,3 etc for each ID?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When asking a question, please give more details, such as what you have tried so far and your current query.  Thanks for including both sample data and desired output.  That helps us answer your question.

Comment: A cross tab is another way of doing this. It is generally faster than PIVOT and is much easier to read in my opinion. The question then is do you have a set number of values per ID or is the number dynamic?

Comment: @SeanLange what do you mean by "cross tab"?  How is it faster?

Comment: Here is an article about static cross tabs. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/

Comment: For the dynamic version you can view this one. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be best if in the future you can provide ddl and sample data. I did this for you this time.

Here is how you could do this if you know the number of elements per row. I put links in the comments of the original post to both the static and dynamic versions of this type of approach.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    ID int,
    Subject1 varchar(50)
)

insert #Something
select 10868952, 'NUR/3110/D507' union all
select 10868952, 'NUR/3110/D512' union all
select 10868952, 'NUR/4010/D523' union all
select 10868952, 'NUR/4010/HD20';

with OrderedResults as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID order by Subject1) as RowNum
    from #Something
)

select ID
 , MAX(Case when RowNum = 1 then Subject1 end) as Subject1
 , MAX(Case when RowNum = 2 then Subject1 end) as Subject2
 , MAX(Case when RowNum = 3 then Subject1 end) as Subject3
 , MAX(Case when RowNum = 4 then Subject1 end) as Subject4
from OrderedResults
group by ID
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
There are more than 1000 ID in the list called DD, each ID has 1-10 rows. So the new columns I need would be from Subject1/Catalog/Session to Subject10/Catalog/Session

How did I get table DD:

SELECT DISTINCT ID, RTRIM(ACAD_PLAN)+'/'+RTRIM(PHONE)+'/'+RTRIM(EMAIL) AS'Test1Date/TestID/Compl/TestScore'INTO **DD** FROM ANGELLA WHERE LINE#=4 

SELECT *FROM **DD** 

So I have the table called DD with 2 columns(ID,Subject1/Catalog/Session) already. Don't know if I can use it later or how to continue the rest part start with :

with OrderedResults as

Comment: Shouldn't need to adjust the cte at all. Just add any extra columns to the final select. If you need a dynamic number of columns you will have to do this differently but it is still reasonable.

Comment: You are welcome. If you need to make this a dynamic number of columns post back and I can help you with that.

Comment: It would be awesome to know how to do dynamic number of columns when I don't know how many subjects at most an ID could have especially when the list getting too large. For now I don't need dynamic columns, there'll be maximum 10 subjects an ID has(I look through the list and count it, didn't see any ID took more than 8 subjects so I make it 10 for security. that's how I get 10). so max 10 columns.Then I just continually add 6 more to what you wrote and it works perfect to me now. I load date from excel by choosing import option tho, not sure how to write sql inquiry or procedure to load now.

Comment: OK the dynamic code example for this is far longer than I can fit in a comment so I will add it as a new answer.

Comment: I have one more question here. I have few more tables need to do the same job, after reformatting the columns, I need to do inner join or full outer join among those results. So how can I package this result? I tried name them as a new table, but didn't work..

Comment: Because I was not creating a new table called #something, but using     SELECT DISTINCT ID, RTRIM(ACAD_PLAN)+'/'+RTRIM(PHONE)+'/'+RTRIM(EMAIL) AS'Subject1'INTO #ddd FROM ANGELLA WHERE LINE#=4 
select * from #ddd

with OrderedResults as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID order by Subject1) as RowNum
    from #ddd
) ......

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this as a dynamic pivot. There are a number of concepts going on here. One is a tally table. In this code it is implemented as a cte. In my actual system I have this as a view. It generates 10,000 rows with zero reads. The tally table and most of the other concepts here were learned by the immortal Jeff Moden. If you do not know what a tally table is or how they work, check out Jeff's article here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

I will post some code for how to do this for this example but anybody who is unfamiliar with this technique should read his article. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Here is a full working example of doing this as a dynamic cross tab. When you are satisfied that the sql this generates is safe feel free to uncomment the last two lines.

LAST but certainly not least. Make sure that you fully understand what this code and how it works. It is not going to be my phone that rings at 3am when something goes wrong. You are the one who will have to be there to support this code.

```
if OBJECT_ID('Something') is not null
    drop table Something

create table Something
(
    ID int,
    Subject1 varchar(50)
)

insert Something
select 10868952, 'NUR/3110/D507' union all
select 10868952, 'NUR/3110/D512' union all
select 10868952, 'NUR/4010/D523' union all
select 10868952, 'NUR/4010/HD20' union all
select 12345, 'asdfasdf'
declare @MaxCols int

declare @StaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = 
    'with OrderedResults as
    (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID order by Subject1) as RowNum
        from Something
    )
    select ID';

declare @DynamicPortion nvarchar(max) = '';
declare @FinalStaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = ' from OrderedResults Group by ID order by ID';

with E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS 
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
)

select @DynamicPortion = @DynamicPortion + 
    ', MAX(Case when RowNum = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then Subject1 end) as Subject' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + CHAR(10)
from cteTally t
where t.N <= 
(
    select top 1 Count(*)
    from Something
    group by ID
    order by COUNT(*) desc
)

select @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion

--declare @SqlToExecute nvarchar(max) = @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion;
--exec sp_executesql @SqlToExecute
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to make the result as a table so I can use it join other table?  What I did at the beginning are as below:                         SELECT DISTINCT ID, RTRIM(ACAD_PLAN) AS'Subject1'INTO #Something FROM ANGELLA WHERE LINE#=4 
select * from #Something

with OrderedResults as  .........same as what you did

Comment: You could add "INTO #MyNewTable" in the @FinalStaticPortion variable. That would insert the results into a new table.

Comment: How about the example that is not dynamic number of columns? Just add  "INTO #MyNewTable" after select ID?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking but the basic format for a select into is this: select [Columns] into [SomeTable] FROM ...

Comment: Basically I just need the result can be used as a table, so I can do inner join/ full outer join with other tables in my sql sever. But I need the first answer you did, which is not using dynamic number of columns.

Comment: I got it. it's the same, just add INTO #MyNewTable. Thank you so much!